# Integrate Android Studio Project with Azure Pipelines CI/CD

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm new to Android Studio development and I've been asked to do that.
I want to know how to do that as I tried to do it but I didn't understand it.

The project is on dev.azure.com, and in Kotlin language.

How to start with it and how to be pro (not that pro) in it?
I couldn't find the way to do or even start with it.

I saw the documentation but it didn't help me.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you?If yes,could you accept it as an answer ,so it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily  Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue , you can install "Azure DevOps Services Plugin for Android Studio".

The Azure DevOps Services Plugin for Android Studio allows you to connect to your Git repositories on Azure DevOps Services in a seamless and intuitive way. You can also use this plugin to import your android development projects into Azure DevOps Services or create pull requests in your Azure DevOps Services/TFS Git repository.

**Note**:The plugin is compatible with Android Studio 1.2 and up.

The Azure DevOps Services plugin for Android Studio is available in the [Android Studio Plugin Repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981?pr=androidstudio). The plugin can be installed from Android Studio by browsing the Plugin Repository.

1. In Android Studio, open plugin settings
2. Click the `Browse repositories...` button and search for "Visual Studio Team Services".
3. Click the `Install plugin` button and restart Android Studio.

For details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/java/download-android-studio-plug-in?view=azure-devops).